# Know if all posts are loaded - tumblr infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, infinite-scroll

In a custom Tumblr theme, I'm trying to add a scroll to top link that needs to appear only when all the posts have been loaded(, right after them).

```
{block:IndexPage}
{block:IfInfinitescrolling}
<nav class="pageNav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">⤒</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
{/block:IfInfinitescrolling}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

If I simply add a `nav` with the link, it appears on all pages until all posts are loaded - itself getting loaded numerous times.
How can I tell if all the pages have been loaded and then append or show it?
(Using the standard Cody Sherman/ Proto.jp script from http://codysherman.tumblr.com/tools/infinite-scrolling/code.)

Comment: Afaik `infinite-scrolling` doesn't provide an appended method, or callback. You are probably best using: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Comment: @mikedidthis thanks, will try now and let you know